# Как сделать загрузку с помощью символов на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать анимацию загрузки с помощь символов, как было на DOS или в Ubuntu терминале? 
А символы эти:

1. --
2. /
3. |
4. \

Думал CSS анимация (возможно), но нет. Это относится с JS, а как сделать её: я не понимаю. Как сделать такую анимацию?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не ясен. Можете его как-то более понятно сформулировать?

Comment: Да. Уже исправил.

Comment: Боюсь, что не все знают/помнят, как это выглядит в DDOS/Ubuntu. Без хоть какой-то визуализации сложно будет)

Comment: Ну, во-первых, DOS, а не DDOS (это несколько иной термин), а во-вторых, эти четыре символа сменяют друг друга с задержкой в долю секунды (они выводятся в одной и той же позиции), отчего создаётся эффект анимации. Кто сделает -- оформляйте JS сниппетом, чтобы можно сразу увидеть, работает или нет. ))

Comment: это вполне может быть и css анимацией

Comment: @AK, спасибо за редактирование, ошибся кое чем, DOS это система, а DDOS это атака хакерская. =D Ну ладно, если на одной позиции, то можно сделать так: 
`var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
elem.innerText = "|";` ну и т.д. А зачем я это спросил, это долгий процесс и поэтому мне нужно что-нибудь покороче. [Typed](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) - это плагин для JQuery, созданным одним человеком. Смысл его, что он может сделать анимацию писание текста. Мне нужно тоже самое только вместо текста и писанием его автом., а символами и повтором анимации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и с помощью одного CSS такое осуществить:

```css
body {background-color: blue;}
.loader:before {
  color: white;
  content: '';
  animation: loader 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes loader {
    0% { content: '--' }
    25% { content: '/' }
    50% { content: '|' }
    75% { content: '\5c' }
    100% { content: '--' }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Но к сожалению данный способ будет работать только в малых кругах браузеров, среди которых Google Chrome. Так что всё же лучше, для кроссбраузерности, воспользоваться JavaScript:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = '--';
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = '/';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = '|';
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = '&#92;';
      }, 250);
    }, 250);
  }, 250);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {background-color: blue;}
#loader {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">--</div>
```

Comment: А можно поставить контент белого цвета?

Comment: @Wicopee, да, смотрите, я отредактировал ответ

Comment: В Firefox не работает

Comment: @Yuri Уточните, пожалуйста, в ответе, что это поведение нестандартное и будет работать только в Chrome, так как согласно [спецификации CSS3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) там свойства `content` нету, хотя в Chrome его анимация поддерживается.

Comment: @Wicopee, обратите внимание на изменённый ответ. Я забыл про одну деталь

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы данное решение поддерживалось разными браузерами надо использовать Javascript-функцию `setInteval`, создать массив из строк для анимации и брать для каждого шага следующую строку по индексу:

```js
(function() {
  var chars = [ "--", "/", "|", "\\" ];
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("loader").innerText = chars[index];
    ++index;
    if (index === chars.length) index = 0;
  }, 250);
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

#loader {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
```